# XML with Rails framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing

I want to use xml file and read the content of such xml file to view. I don't know where is the location of xml file in rails framework. Please suggest me where is the suitable directory of xml file in rails framework, how to read xml with rails and how to parse this xml content to ruby hash?

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) a try. See this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri) video.

Comment: Your answer can't cover my question.

Comment: Do you want to render xml file instead of html ?

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how and where to use xml file in rails?

Comment: I need basic help that how to use xml file in rails framework and furthermore. Thanks

Comment: just add a file in the views with .xml extension like the default .html extension. And if you hit the  url .../xyz.xml then it will render the xml version

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. Can you provide me links for more tutorials related to xml with rails.